Trying to sum volume in pivot high on candles range in pinescript v5
It tries to count the volume when reaching pivot high or pivot low in the range of candles given to determine this level. For example, the range of candles to determine the pivot point is right/left 10 candles and I want to count the volume from a range of 20 candles in total, however, what I am trying does not count the volume. Below is the code of the function, maybe someone will have an idea.
get_phpl()=>
    barPhR = 0
    barPhL = 0
    barPlR = 0
    barPlL = 0
    float ph = ta.pivothigh(swing_length, swing_length)
    float pl = ta.pivotlow(swing_length, swing_length)
    phtimestart = ph ? time[swing_length] : na
    pltimestart = pl ? time[swing_length] : na
    Greenvolume = 0.0
    Redvolume = 0.0
    TotalVolume = 0.0
    if not na (ph)
        barPhR := phtimestart[swing_length]
        barPhL := phtimestart
        for i = barPhL to barPhR            
            if close[i] > open[i]
                Greenvolume := nz(Greenvolume[1]) + volume[i]
            if close[i] < open[i]
                Redvolume := nz(Redvolume[1]) + volume[i]
            TotalVolume := TotalVolume[i] + volume[i]
        
    else if not na (pl)
        barPlR := pltimestart[swing_length]
        barPlL := pltimestart
        for i = barPlL to barPlR
            if close[i] > open[i]
                Greenvolume := nz(Greenvolume[1]) + volume[i]
            if close[i] < open[i]
                Redvolume := nz(Redvolume[1]) + volume[i]
            TotalVolume := TotalVolume[i] + volume[i]
    
    if Greenvolume > 0
        Greenvolume := Greenvolume / TotalVolume 
    else
        Greenvolume := 0.0
    if Redvolume > 0
        Redvolume := Redvolume / TotalVolume
    else
        Redvolume := 0.0

    [ph, phtimestart, pl, pltimestart, Greenvolume, Redvolume]

[swing_high, phtimestart, swing_low, pltimestart, GV, RV] = get_phpl()

